# jquery: Click callback for any node except a certain node

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to write a click callback function for if you click anywhere BUT the header. Right now here is my DOM structure:

[image]

I'm targeting `.wrapper-main` and `footer` like this (below) since these are the elements that are NOT the `header`. But I'm hoping there can be a more generic way, so that if you had this same `header` on another page without `.wrapper-main` and `footer` and you clicked anywhere BUT the `header` it would execute the click callback, `closeNavOnMobile`.

```
$('.wrapper-main').click( function () {
  closeNavOnMobile();
});

$('footer').click( function () {
  closeNavOnMobile();
});

function closeNavOnMobile(){
  // slide up the mobile nav menu 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use code like this for my current project. It fires on all clicks in the document. But uses a simple if to filter out the header and the headers child elements.

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
    var header =  $(".header-main");

    if (!header.is(e.target) && header.has(e.target).length === 0) {
        closeNavOnMobile()
    }
});
```

Comment: You can optimize the second half of your `if` statement by doing `&& !$.contains(header[0], e.target)`. It avoids creating a new jQuery object and performing a filter operation. jQuery will use the built-in `.contains()` method, which is very fast. Unfortunately, they made it non-compliant with the DOM spec, so you still need the `.is()`.

Comment: Nice recommendation. Will look into it later. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just check if the `event.target` is inside the header.

```js
function closeNavOnMobile(event) {
  if (document.querySelector("header").contains(event.target)) {
    return; // In the header, so exit the function
  } 

  // the rest of your code.
  alert("CLICKED");
}

document.body.addEventListener("click", closeNavOnMobile);
```

```css
header {
  height: 100px;
  background: orange;
}
.wrapper-main {
  height: 200px;
  background: pink;
}
footer {
  height: 100px;
  background: teal;
}
```

```html
<header>
 HEADER PREVENT CLICKS IN HERE
</header>
<div class="wrapper-main">WRAPPER</div>
<footer>FOOTER</footer>
```

You can do something similar in jQuery if you wish.